# code from codepen not working when I put it in my editor (VSCode)

Tags: html, css, sass, linker, codepen

I am trying to link my html and css and I want to add certain type of button to my website however it correctly puts the information on the html but the style is not being showcased on the my page.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <button>Upload</button>
    <button>Preview</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

style.css:

```
@import "https://unpkg.com/open-props";

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: var(--gray-12);
}


button {
  font-family: var(--font-sans);
  font-weight: var(--font-weight-6);
  font-size: var(--font-size-5);
  color: var(--gray-8);
  background: var(--gray-0);
  border: 0;
  padding: var(--size-4) var(--size-8);
  transform: translateY(calc(var(--y, 0) * 1%)) scale(var(--scale));
  transition: transform 0.1s;
  position: relative;
}

button:hover {
  --y: -10;
  --scale: 1.1;
  --border-scale: 1;
}

button:active {
  --y: 5%;
  --scale: 0.9;
  --border-scale: 0.9, 0.8;
}

button:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  inset: calc(var(--size-3) * -1);
  border: var(--size-2) solid var(--gray-0);
  transform: scale(var(--border-scale, 0));
  transition: transform 0.125s;
  
  --angle-one: 105deg;
  --angle-two: 290deg;
  --spread-one: 30deg;
  --spread-two: 40deg;
  --start-one: calc(var(--angle-one) - (var(--spread-one) * 0.5));
  --start-two: calc(var(--angle-two) - (var(--spread-two) * 0.5));
  --end-one: calc(var(--angle-one) + (var(--spread-one) * 0.5));
  --end-two: calc(var(--angle-two) + (var(--spread-two) * 0.5));
  
  mask: conic-gradient(
    transparent 0 var(--start-one),
    white var(--start-one) var(--end-one),
    transparent var(--end-one) var(--start-two),
    white var(--start-two) var(--end-two),
    transparent var(--end-two)
  );
  
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Please help me solving this issue.
I also get this message which I know is an error but do not know how to solve it. I got the css for code pen.
"127.0.0.1 - - [15/May/2023 14:17:21] "GET /style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -" when my

I crossed checked everything my files are in the same directory however my html page is still not showing the styles mentioned in the CSS. I also checked the post where it says why code pen code doesn't work sometimes however, I was having troubling understanding the solution so if someone can explain in layman's term or simpler terms I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Can you please try removing the css inside of your style.css file and just write a very basic style to check if there are any wrong styles in your file. For example the `mask:` property inside the css feels like this code might not be in css but less or sass or maybe some other type. The very basic style to check for would be 
`
body {
 background-color: red;
}
`

Comment: The error "404 - Not Found" means that file was not found on the server. Are you sure that your style.css file and index.html are in the same folder? Double check your file names maybe there is a typo, letter case is not capitalized?  Also try to remove `@import "https://unpkg.com/open-props";`